# I can't seem to properly parse XML data in JS

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have an input field with this text in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<players timestamp="1536505850">
  <player id="0518" name="Eagles, Philadelphia" position="Def" team="PHI" />
  <player id="10271" name="Jones, Julio" position="WR" team="ATL" />
  <player id="12154" name="Ajayi, Jay" position="RB" team="PHI" />
</players>
```

I have these variables:

```
var outputField = document.getElementById('output');
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(document.getElementById('output'), "text/xml");
```

When I call this:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("player")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined at :1:41

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *player* elements don't have child nodes. You need to shorten the line which produces the error from

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("player")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

to

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("player")[0].nodeValue;
```

It would be good to know what you're trying to access though, because the statement above will evaluate to `null`:

```js
var outputField = document.getElementById('output');

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(outputField.value, "text/xml");

console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("player")[0].nodeValue);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<textarea id="output">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<players timestamp="1536505850">
  <player id="0518" name="Eagles, Philadelphia" position="Def" team="PHI" />
  <player id="10271" name="Jones, Julio" position="WR" team="ATL" />
  <player id="12154" name="Ajayi, Jay" position="RB" team="PHI" />
</players>
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE:** Here's an example of how to get an attribute from an "player" element:

```js
var outputField = document.getElementById('output');

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(outputField.value, "text/xml");

console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("player")[0].getAttribute('name'));
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<textarea id="output">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<players timestamp="1536505850">
  <player id="0518" name="Eagles, Philadelphia" position="Def" team="PHI" />
  <player id="10271" name="Jones, Julio" position="WR" team="ATL" />
  <player id="12154" name="Ajayi, Jay" position="RB" team="PHI" />
</players>
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would you access a specific value, for example the name of the first player? I thought doing `console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("player")[0]` would return all of the values of the first player.

Comment: @CalW No, `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("player")[0]` returns the first element with tag name "player" in the document.  You are looking for `Element.getAttribute(name: string)`. I updated my answer to get the name attribute of the first "player" element.